# Using grep with sed for desired match

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have the following lines of code below

```
BalancerMember http://node9:29080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=tc_node9  status=D
BalancerMember http://node10:29080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=tc_node10  status=D
BalancerMember http://node11:29080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=tc_node11
BalancerMember http://node9:29080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=jb_node9  status=D
```

I need to search for all lines with `tc_` pattern and add the `status=D` keyword at the end of line . Also if there is already `status=D` has been added to lines with `tc_` pattern , then those lines should be ignored. In the above example I need to change line 3 and rest lines needs to be ignored.

To add `status=D` to the end of lines , I used the following below code

```
sed  -i '/tc_/s/$/ status=D/'  app.conf
```

and to ignore lines with already `status=D in tc_` pattern , I am using the below code

```
   grep -E tc_  app.conf | grep -v  -E status=D
```

After that I combined both the codes as follows

```
  grep -E tc_  app.conf | grep -v  -E status=D | sed  -i '/tc_/s/$/ status=D/'
```

It gives the following error

```
sed:  no input files
```

For this if I add the file name with `sed -i` , then it reads the entire file and the results of `grep` expression are ignored.

Probably I have to do all the work with a singlr `sed` command. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is your friend

```
sed -E '/status=D[[:blank:]]*$/!{/tc_/{s/$/ status=D/}}' file_name
```

gives you the required output

```
BalancerMember http://node9:29080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=tc_node9  status=D
BalancerMember http://node10:29080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=tc_node10  status=D
BalancerMember http://node11:29080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=tc_node11 status=D
BalancerMember http://node9:29080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=jb_node9  status=D
```

**Long story short**

Essentially, what we do here is look for files that end with `status=D` and  skip those lines. For all the other lines do check if it has `tc_` in them and append a `status=D` at the end.

**Short story long**

- `/pattern/` looks for a pattern.
- `{group of commands separated with semicolon}` groups commands.
- `!{group of commands}` means the group of commands will not be executed. Mind the semicolon in the beginning.
- `/pattern/!{group of commands}` means the group of commands will not be executed if the pattern is found and will be executed if the pattern is not found.
- `s/pattern/replacement/` looks for the pattern and if found replaces it with the replacement, and
- `[:blank:]` is a regex class and `[[:blank:]]` is another way of writing `[ \t]`. Check [[ this ]](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) and `*` means zero or more.
- `s/$/replacement/` means look for the end of the line(`$` in pattern means the end of line,also `^` means beginning) and replaces it with `replacement`.

Hope things are clear :)

Comment: Thanks . That works. Can you please explain how each of them work

Comment: @ZamaQues Added explanation. :) and thanks for accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`awk` solution:

```
awk '/tc_/ && !/status=D$/ {$0=$0 " status=D" }1' file
```

Updated `sed` solution with condition nesting :

```
sed '/tc_/{ /status=D$/! s/^.*$/& status=D/ }' file
```

Comment: This will not work...If there is already "status=D" there in the line , it is appending one more. It should ignore those lines

Comment: That awk solution is the correct answer except you should be appending to `$0`, not `$NF` since you don't want to recompile the record and potentially mess up any existing white space. Also lose the `$` from the end of the regexp (or replace it with `[[:blank:]]*$`) as it's not necessary and if that script isn't working for the OP then he must have existing trailing white space.